# Methods .endswith/.removesuffix) not removing suffixes

Tags: python, suffix, ends-with

I am trying to remove suffixes but for some reason, it is not working.
Code is:

```
# Stemming
    suffix_list = ['-ed', '-ing', '-s']

    for word in range(len(output)):  # loop
        # range returns the sequence, len checks the lenght
        for suffix in range(len(suffix_list)):
            # .endswith checks x in both
            if output[word].endswith(suffix_list[suffix]):
                # .removesuffix removes from output if in suffix_list
                print(output[word].removesuffix(suffix_list[suffix]))

    return output

print(textPreprocessing("I'm gathering herbs."))
print(textPreprocessing("When life gives you lemons, make lemonade"))
```

Outcome is:

```
gather
herb
['im', 'gathering', 'herbs']
give
lemon
['life', 'gives', 'you', 'lemons', 'make', 'lemonade']
```

Where it should be:

```
['im', 'gather', 'herbs']
['life', 'give', 'you', 'lemon', 'make', 'lemonade']
```

Any help?
I feel like I am missing something obvious...

Comment: You are printing the results in the function, but then returning `output`, and then printing that return value.

Comment: Is the dash before each suffix necessary?

Comment: The problem is that `removesuffix` return the new word without the suffix and doesn't apply the changes on the existing variable.

Comment: In addition you are iterating over characters and not words

Answer (score 0):

```
output[word] = output[word].removesuffix(suffix_list[suffix])
```

Comment: I see what I missed, thanks for the help!!! Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:-

```py
str_sample = "When life gives you lemons make lemonade"
suffixes, words = ["s"], str_sample.split()

for i in range(len(suffixes)):
    for j in range(len(words)):
        if words[j].endswith(suffixes[i]):
            words[j] = words[j].replace(f"{suffixes[i]}", "")

print(words)
```

It can be compressed to a List Comprehension as :-

```py
str_sample = "When life gives you lemons make lemonade"
suffixes, words = ["s"], str_sample.split()

res = [words[j].replace(f"{suffixes[i]}", "") if words[j].endswith(suffixes[i]) else words[j] for j in range(len(words)) for i in range(len(suffixes))]

print(words)
```